# How to sort a list of dict based on their datetime in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, datetime

I have below list:

```
[
    {
        "attributes": 
        [
            {
                "label": "Event Date",
                "value": "Tue, 29 Jun 2021 18:30:00 GMT"
            }
        ],
        "event": "DT2"
    },
    {
        "attributes": 
        [
            {
                "label": "DT3",
                "value": true
            },
            {
                "label": "Event Date",
                "value": "Thu, 22 Jul 2021 18:30:00 GMT"
            }
        ],
        "event": "DT5"
    },
    {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "label": "DT6",
                "value": 1.0
            },
            {
                "label": "Event Date",
                "value": "Thu, 08 Jul 2021 18:30:00 GMT"
            }
        ],
        "event": "DT7"
    }
]
```

Above data is a `list` of `dict`. Each `dict` has a `list` of `attributes`. `attriutes` is again a dict which has many items and `Event Date`. I have to sort all the dicts inside list based on ascending order of `Event Date`. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Define a function `k(d)` that examines a dict `d` and returns the date. Then sort your list `l` using `sort(l, key=k)`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA full list

Comment: It always contain field `Event Date` and the datetime , right?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Yes it always contain field Event Date and the datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sort by key.

This is how you would do it for a simpler example:

```py
my_list = [
    {
        "foo": 5,
        "bar": 4,
    },
    {
        "foo": 3,
        "bar": 2,
    },
    {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": 0,
    },
]

# This will sort the list according to the "foo" in each dictionary.
my_list.sort(key=lambda dictionary: dictionary["foo"])
```

For your specific case, since it is more complicated, I would create a function instead of using a lambda expression. Additionally, I will use `datetime` to help me compare the date strings.

```py
from datetime import datetime

def key_function(dictionary):
    attributes = dictionary["attributes"]
    for attribute in attributes:
        if attribute["label"] == "Event Date":
            date_string = attribute["value"]
            date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z")
            # Compare dates according to their POSIX timestamp
            # I am assuming the dates will be after 1970
            return date.timestamp()
    raise ValueError("Event Date attribute wasn't found")

my_list.sort(key=key_function)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the datetime string firstly, then format the datetime string:

```
import datetime

lst = [
    {
        "attributes": 
        [
            {
                "label": "Event Date",
                "value": "Tue, 29 Jun 2021 18:30:00 GMT"
            }
        ],
        "event": "DT2"
    },
    {
        "attributes": 
        [
            {
                "label": "DT3",
                "value": True
            },
            {
                "label": "Event Date",
                "value": "Thu, 22 Jul 2021 18:30:00 GMT"
            }
        ],
        "event": "DT5"
    },
    {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "label": "DT6",
                "value": 1.0
            },
            {
                "label": "Event Date",
                "value": "Thu, 08 Jul 2021 18:30:00 GMT"
            }
        ],
        "event": "DT7"
    }
]
    
lst.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(next(attr["value"] for attr in x["attributes"] if attr["label"] == "Event Date"), "%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z"))
```

Or more readable way:

```
def check(x):
    for attr in x["attributes"]:
        if attr["label"] == "Event Date":
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(attr["value"], "%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z")
 
lst.sort(key=check)
```

And gave me:

```
[{'attributes': [{'label': 'Event Date',
    'value': 'Tue, 29 Jun 2021 18:30:00 GMT'}],
  'event': 'DT2'},
 {'attributes': [{'label': 'DT6', 'value': 1.0},
   {'label': 'Event Date', 'value': 'Thu, 08 Jul 2021 18:30:00 GMT'}],
  'event': 'DT7'},
 {'attributes': [{'label': 'DT3', 'value': True},
   {'label': 'Event Date', 'value': 'Thu, 22 Jul 2021 18:30:00 GMT'}],
  'event': 'DT5'}]
```